# Messages disappearing out of MQ when the application stopped

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms, mq

We have a spring application read the messages from IBM MQ and we implemented transaction logic as well. If the application failed to process, we put back the messages into MQ.

We have 100s of messages in MQ and application reading one message. If application failed to process then put back to the queue. All messages are disappearing when I stop the application gracefully after putting back message to MQ.

When I kill the process of the application, messages are not disappearing.

Is there an issue at transactions lever?

Comment: after you put them back to the queue, do you commit those again ? Try one more MQCMIT when you do the graceful shutdown. If that's not working, can you post your example code here ?

Comment: Are the messages that disappear messages that you put back to the queue?  Do you manually put them back to the queue or is it via the JMS backout method?

Comment: @JoshMc, Actually application is reading only one message and all other messages are still in the queue. Application putting back the message if it failed to process. all messages are disappearing when we stop the application gracefully.

Comment: Do you manually put them back to the queue or is it via the JMS backout method? What is the source of the messages that disappear.

Comment: We are using XA transactions. The application put back the message to the queue If it fails to process.